# Wordpress 4.0 Broken Menu

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

I updated to WP 4.0 the other day and noticed that my menus were resorting to the first alphabetical menu available. I did some searching and found that quite a few other people were having the same issue. So far, the only answer I've seen on this issue is here:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-40-broke-main-menu?replies=25

The user "lblechl" wrote "Verify the argument arrays you send to wp_nav_menu do not contain any trailing characters, extra commas, incorrect parameters, etc."

I looked through my theme, and compared it to the original version of the Bones Development Theme, but I can't seem to see what the problem would be. Has anyone else experienced this?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
// REGISTERING THE MENU
function bones_theme_support() {
register_nav_menus(
    array(
        'mobile-nav' => __( 'The Mobile Menu', 'bonestheme' )   // main nav in header
    )
);
}
// END REGISTERING THE MENU

// THE MENU
function bones_mobile_nav() {
wp_nav_menu(array(
    'container' => false, // remove nav container
    'container_class' => '', // class of container (should you choose to use it)
    'menu' => __( 'The Mobile Menu', 'bonestheme' ), // nav name
    'menu_class' => '', // adding custom nav class
    'theme_location' => '', // where it's located in the theme
    'before' => '', // before the menu
    'after' => '', // after the menu
    'link_before' => '', // before each link
    'link_after' => '', // after each link
    'depth' => 0, // limit the depth of the nav
    'fallback_cb' => 'bones_mobile_nav_fallback' // fallback function
));
}
/* END THE MENU */

// THE FALLBACK
function bones_mobile_nav_fallback() {
    wp_page_menu( array(
    'show_home' => true,
    'menu_class' => '', // adding custom nav class
    'include'     => '',
    'exclude'     => '',
    'echo'        => true,
    'link_before' => '', // before each link
    'link_after' => '' // after each link
) );
}
/* END THE FALLBACK */
```

Answer (score 0):

At first I tried to set the 'menu' key in wp_nav_menu() to the $location and $description like this:

```
// Registering the menu:
register_nav_menu( 'my_menu', 'My Menu');

// Inside the view I tried with the $location:
wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'my_menu'))

// and with the $description:
wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'My Menu'))
```

Neither worked until I tried with the Menu Name you set in:

```
yoursite.com/wp-admin/nav-menus.php
```

Lets say I set the Menu Name to "Example Menu"

Then, in the view replace the menu value with the Menu Name you set before (yoursite.com/wp-admin/nav-menus.php):

```
wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'Example Menu'))
```

This got me thinking, I probably didn't understand correctly the documentation since I thought you could use both the $location and $description from the revister_nav_menu() in wp_nav_menu().

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:** In your case I see you are using a localization helper "__()" in the menu key which I don't know if has a special use inside WP, but my guess is you should not be using it:

```
function bones_mobile_nav() {
  wp_nav_menu(array(
   //...
   // This is how you are doing it:
   'menu' => __( 'The Mobile Menu', 'bonestheme' ),
   //The value should be the string set in yoursite.com/wp-admin/nav-menus.php:
   'menu' => 'Example Menu',
   //...
  ));
}
```

Comment: You don't ever want to edit the contents of the wp-admin folder directly as they may be overridden in future code updates and your changes would be lost resulting in a maintenance nightmare as noted here http://codex.wordpress.org/Files_Automatically_Replaced_by_Core_Upgrade.

Comment: Edrpls, you would (typically) want to use the __() function for internationalization when creating plugins or themes for use in multiple languages. That way translations for 'The Mobile Menu' can be displayed in Spanish, German, etc. later down the road, provided WordPress has been configured to handle multiple languages. I can verify using the function in the menu shouldn't prevent the code from working from personal results in WP 4.0. It's a best practice, but isn't required if you don't care about other language translations and don't intend to share your code with the world.

Comment: Luke, I meant to edit the wp configuration from the dashboard, not editing directly any wp-admin files. Also, thanks for the clarification on the __()

Comment: No problem, and thanks much for the clarification as well from your end.

Answer (score 0):

This is 'lblechl' from the WP forums you mentioned.

With the code provided, I'm noticing register_nav_menus call is wrapped in a function. Is anything in the code calling the bones_theme_support function? If not, you will have to hook that function into something when your theme is loaded.

Also, verify 'The Mobile Menu' is the exact name of the Menu created.

Keep me posted on more details if both of these seem to be in order and you're still having issues.

Comment: Yeah the bones_theme_support is being called. I've also verified the menu name, and it seems to be okay. This has actually been an issue with several websites (some were purchased themes, and some were custom built using bones) since the update for 4.0.